# Checking for Intersect after lose focus

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to check if the user just lost focus from a specific `Range` of cells.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static OldRange As Range
    Dim AmountCol As String * 1
    Dim PayedCol As String * 1
    Dim MyRange As Range

    If (Not OldRange Is Nothing) Then
        AmountCol = Chr(Asc(Range("B1").Text) + 1)
        PayedCol = Chr(Asc(Range("B1").Text) + 2)
        Set MyRange = Range(AmountCol & ":" & AmountCol)

        If Not MyRange Is Nothing And Not OldRange Is Nothing Then
            If Not Intersect(OldRange, MyRange) Then
                MsgBox Chr(Asc(Range("B1").Text) + 1) & ":" & Chr(Asc(Range("B1").Text) + 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set OldRange = Target.Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me understand what's wrong with this? The code breaks on the line with `If Not Intersect(OldRange, MyRange) Then`.

Comment: How about removing the brackets around `Not OldRange Is Nothing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
If Not Intersect(OldRange, MyRange) Then
```

to this:

```
If Intersect(OldRange, MyRange) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to keep the `Not` though